# TeraTerm のマクロで while 文から条件に応じて if 文で抜けるには

Tags: teraterm

TeraTermのマクロでの動作の質問です。

Whileでshowコマンドを何秒かごとに流し込む繰り返しを作り、Enterが押されたら抜けるような仕組みを作りたいのですが、IfとWaitを駆使してどうにかならないでしょうか？

イメージでは通常はWaitで一つの `#` を待つところ、Enterを押すことで `#` が2度表示されるので、If文で `#` が2つ続いたら、Breakするような仕組みは難しいのでしょうか。

```basic
;コマンドを繰り返す
cnt = 1
while cnt

sendln 'show log | grep up'

wait '#'

sendln 'show log | grep down'

wait '#'

yesnobox 'もう一回？' 'Message'

if result = 0 then
    cnt = cnt - 1
endif

endwhile

mpause 5000
```

現在は方法が分からず、上記のように `yesnobox` で対応しています。
なお、機器はYAMAHAのFWX-120を使用しています。

何か方法がありましたら、よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

何秒か待機する[`mpause`](http://ttssh2.osdn.jp/manual/ja/macro/command/mpause.html)の代替として[`mtimeout`](https://ttssh2.osdn.jp/manual/ja/macro/syntax/variables.html)と[`recvln`](https://ttssh2.osdn.jp/manual/ja/macro/command/recvln.html)を組み合わせることで、割込入力待ちしながら待機できませんか？

下記のコードはlinux上で任意の処理(ここではpingとsleep)と3秒待機を繰り返しながら無限ループしています。
`check_input`ラベルが呼ばれるたびに3秒まで入力を待ち、その間に空白文字(スペースや改行文字)のみ入力されると正規表現にヒットして`exit`でマクロが終了します。

```
while 1
  sendln 'ping 127.0.0.1 -c 2 -i 0.5' ; 任意の処理
  wait '#' '$'                        ; 処理完了まで待機
  call check_input

  sendln 'sleep 1'                    ; 任意の処理その2
  wait '#' '$'                        ; 処理完了まで待機
  call check_input
endwhile

; スリープしながら入力チェック
:check_input
  timeout = 3                         ; タイムアウトを3秒に設定
  recvln                              ; タイムアウトまでスリープしながら入力チェック
  if result = 1 then                  ; 何かが入力された
    strmatch inputstr '.+[$#]\s*$'    ; 末尾が$か#の後に空白文字(スペースや改行文字)のみ
    if result = 1 then                ; 上記正規表現に合致
      exit                            ; マクロ終了
    endif
  endif
  timeout = 0                         ; タイムアウトを無限(初期値)に戻す
  return                              ; 呼び出し元に戻る
```